# GData spreadsheet text_db client authentication using Google OAuth 2

Tags: python-2.7, spreadsheet, gdata

how can i use google oauth token with gdata.spreadsheet.text_db?
I am using DatabaseClient but it needs username and password as parameters (and i don't want that)
Is there any function or method to replace the login of username and password with google oauth token?

```
client = gdata.spreadsheet.text_db.DatabaseClient(username, passwd)
db = client.GetDatabases(name="google docs example")[0]
```